# Active Record and queries with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I am using codeigniter for my application and i am a bit confused, I wrote some queries like that:

```
public function checkemail($email) {
    $this->db->select('email')->from('user')->where('email', $email);
}
```

But in the manual of codeigniter ( http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html ) they talk about $this->db->get();
Should I add it after the $this->db->select query?

My function works fine...

When should I use get() ?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to run `get()` after the other methods.  `select()`, `from()` and `where()` add their respective statements to the query, and get() actually runs the query and returns the result as an object.

In this case, you could just add it on to the end of the chain.

```
public function checkemail($email) {
    $this->db
        ->select('email')
        ->from('user')
        ->where('email', $email)
        ->get();
}
```

If you want to work with the result afterwards, make sure that you are assigning it to a variable.

```
$user = $this->db
    ->select('email')
    ->from('user')
    ->where('email', $email)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But do you know why my query is executed anyway without the get() ?

I call it like that: 
$this->s_model->checkemail($email);

Comment: Hmm, I didn't even realize that queries would run without calling the get() method on them.  Does it still return an object that you can run the query result methods on? (i.e. `result()`, `result_array()`, etc.)

Comment: Yes, I mean I call this after and it works:
if ($this->db->count_all_results() == 0){ ... }

Comment: `count_all_results()` doesn't operate on a query result object like `result()` and `result_array()` would. If you are using SQL, this would be same as executing a COUNT query. The equivalent method for finding the number of rows returned on an actual query object is `num_rows()`.

Comment: I don't believe that your query is actually being executed. Just try chaining one of the query result methods (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) on the end of that and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you Chris and Stef, I have managed to get it work.<br/><br/>

    $query = $this->db->select('email')->from($user)->where('email', $value_email)->get();
      if ($query->num_rows() == 1){
       foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        $result = $row->email;
       }
       ...
      }
<br/><br/>
Thanks for the hints!
<br/><br/>
I have a last question if I may:<br/>
Am I obliged to do a foreach if I know that I have only one result? Or how can I use directly $query for example (the value of the email of the user)?<br/>
I don't know if I'm clear...?

Comment: You can just use `row()` on the result if you know there is only one result.  If there is more than one result it will take the first one and return it as an object.  I'm not sure I understand why stef's answer was marked as correct and not mine :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `get("table_name")` then you don't need to use `from("table_name")`. It's just an alternative syntax it seems.

From the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html), all the way at the bottom it says: *As shown earlier, the FROM portion of your query can be specified in the $this->db->get() function, so use whichever method you prefer.*